# Usar lapply dentro de loop for?

Tags: r

Gostaria de gerar `nBS` reamostras para cada um dos `N` vetores coluna de tamanho `n` da minha matriz, e retornar então algo como uma lista.

Consegui algo parecido com o desejado com o seguinte (testando com valores iguais no vetor para ter certeza que as reamostras são das respectivas colunas):

```
v1 = c(1,3,2,4,1)
v2 = c(2,2,2,2,2)
dados = matrix(c(v1,v2),ncol = 2)
N = ncol(dados)
n = nrow(dados)
nBS <- 5

for (i in 1:N){
    y = dados[,i]
    lst <- lapply(1:N, function(x) matrix(sample(y,n,T), nrow = n, ncol = nBS))
}
```

Mas minha saída aparentemente indica que só o `v2` foi usado nessa reamostragem:

```
>  lst 
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2    2    2
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2
[5,]    2    2    2    2    2

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2    2    2
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2
[5,]    2    2    2    2    2
```

Como faço para percorrer todas as colunas da minha matriz e retornar `nBS` reamostras de tamanho `n` para cada um dos meus `N` vetores?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer de várias maneiras, aqui vão três delas.

Em ambas o trabalho todo é feito por

```
apply(dados, 2, sample, n, TRUE)
```

A diferença está em como chamar esta instrução.

**1ª**

Combinar `replicate` com `apply`. O resultado é um `"array"` com 3 dimensões. A **terceira dimensão** é `nBS`, as duas primeiras são as dimensões da matriz original.

```
set.seed(1234)
res1 <- replicate(nBS, apply(dados, 2, sample, n, TRUE))
```

**2ª**

Combinar `lapply` com `apply`.

```
set.seed(1234)
res2 <- lapply(seq_len(nBS), function(i) apply(dados, 2, sample, n, TRUE))
```

Desta vez o resultado é uma lista, um objeto de classe `"list"`. Para comparar os resultados vou usar `identical` em ciclo.

```
for(i in seq_len(nBS)) 
  print(identical(res1[,, i], res2[[i]]))

#[1] TRUE
#[1] TRUE
#[1] TRUE
#[1] TRUE
#[1] TRUE
```

**3ª**

Desta vez com um ciclo `for`. Os resultados vão ser atribuídos aos membros de uma lista previamente criada.

```
set.seed(1234)
res3 <- vector("list", length = nBS)
for(i in seq_len(nBS)){
  res3[[i]] <- apply(dados, 2, sample, n, TRUE)
}
```

Como tanto `res2` como `res3` são listas, podemos comparar diretamente.

```
identical(res2, res3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Funcionando lindamente do jeito que preciso! Resposta clara e completíssima!