# Usar lapply dentro de loop for? [2]

Tags: r

Sobre a pergunta em:

[Usar lapply dentro de loop for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399086/usar-lapply-dentro-de-loop-for)

Preciso acessar minha matriz em partes (pois o procedimento gera um problema com o limite de memória disponível para o R, dada a dimensão grande da minha matriz inicial --500 colunas, de tamanho 200--). Por exemplo:

```
for(j in 1:100){
    set.seed(1234)
    res2 <- lapply(seq_len(nBS), function(i) apply(dados[,j,drop=F], 2, sample, n, TRUE))
}
```

Quando faço isso, apenas a coluna `j = 100` é usada.

Como faço para usar todos os vetores da minha matriz nesse loop for (de 1 a 100)?

Alguma sugestão para fazer isso de forma mais eficiente para as 500 colunas?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: 1) Ponha o `set.seed` fora do ciclo `for`. 2) Inicialize `res2 <- vector("list", 100)` também fora do ciclo. 3) Dentro do ciclo, `res2[[j]] <- lapply(etc)`.

Comment: 4) Finalmente, talvez seja melhor usar a 2ª solução da resposta do link com `function(i) apply(dados[, 1:100], etc)`. Se fizer isto escusa de inicializar a variável `res2` como eu disse no ponto 2) acima. É fazer exatamente como está nessa resposta só com a diferença do conjunto de dados que passrá a ser um subconjunto da base `dados`. Depois de processar esse subconjunto, pode-se repetir com `dados[, 101:200]` etc até todas as 500 colunas.

Comment: Obrigada!! A solução 4) é ótima!